# SQL Server, insert value to variable and sort

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to sort the results of a query after insert a value to a variable.
I am trying to sort according to 'RowId' but its not valid in my case.
Below is my query, how can I make it work?
Thanks.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @NumOfProducts = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Products.Id) AS RowId 
        FROM          Cities INNER JOIN
                      CitiesInLanguages ON Cities.Id = CitiesInLanguages.CityId INNER JOIN
                      ShopsInCities ON Cities.Id = ShopsInCities.CityId INNER JOIN
                      Categories INNER JOIN
                      ProductstInCategories ON Categories.Id = ProductstInCategories.CategoryId INNER JOIN
                      Products ON ProductstInCategories.ProductId = Products.Id INNER JOIN
                      ProductsInProdutGroup ON Products.Id = ProductsInProdutGroup.ProductId INNER JOIN
                      ProductsGroups ON ProductsInProdutGroup.ProductGroupId = ProductsGroups.Id INNER JOIN
                      ShopsInProductsGroup ON ProductsGroups.Id = ShopsInProductsGroup.ProductGroupId INNER JOIN
                      aspnet_Users ON ShopsInProductsGroup.ShopId = aspnet_Users.UserId ON ShopsInCities.ShopId = aspnet_Users.UserId INNER JOIN
                      ProductsNamesInLanguages ON Products.Id = ProductsNamesInLanguages.ProductId INNER JOIN
                      UsersInfo ON aspnet_Users.UserId = UsersInfo.UserId INNER JOIN
                      ProductOptions ON Products.Id = ProductOptions.ProductId INNER JOIN
                      ProductOptionsInLanguages ON ProductOptions.Id = ProductOptionsInLanguages.ProductOptionId INNER JOIN
                      ProductFiles ON Products.Id = ProductFiles.ProductId INNER JOIN
                      ProductsInOccasions ON Products.Id = ProductsInOccasions.ProductId INNER JOIN
                      Occasions ON ProductsInOccasions.OccasionId = Occasions.Id INNER JOIN
                      OccasionsInLanguages ON Occasions.Id = OccasionsInLanguages.OccasionId
WHERE     (Products.IsAddition = 0) AND (Categories.IsEnable = 1) AND (Products.IsEnable = 1) AND (ProductsGroups.IsEnable = 1) AND (Cities.IsEnable = 1) AND 
                      (ShopsInProductsGroup.IsEnable = 1) AND (CitiesInLanguages.CityName = @CityName) AND (ProductsNamesInLanguages.LanguageId = @languageId) AND 
                      (Categories.Id = @CategoryId) AND (ProductOptions.IsEnable = 1) AND (ProductFiles.IsEnable = 1)
                      group by Products.Id, ProductsNamesInLanguages.ProductName, UsersInfo.Name
                      Order By RowId
```

Answer (score 1):

With edit try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @NumOfProducts = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Products.Id),
                              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Products.Id) AS RowId
```

or try

```
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Products.Id)
```

I'd have to test but I thik both will work.

---

The problem is that rowid is not in any of the group by items.

You could order by `Products.id`.  If `rowid` is going to be the same for each one you could order by `max(rowid)` or `min(rowid)` or add `rowid` to the group by statement.

Comment: Sorry,  I forgot to add the @NumOfProducts which cause all the problem.

Comment: That is not valid SQL you can't assign to a variable and give it an alias.  But I think you can just put `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Products.Id)` after the `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find the ID of the most recently inserted row? You want

```
 SELECT Scope_Identity()
```

**Edit**
*I am trying to get the max row id of ROW_NUMBER()*

Wrap your query in

```
 SELECT  @NumOfProducts = Max(RowID) FROM
 ( [your query here] ) v
```

Alternately, a `SELECT COUNT`... query may provide the answer

Comment: Sorry,  I forgot to add the @NumOfProducts which cause all the problem.

Comment: No, I am trying to get the max row id of ROW_NUMBER(). the problem is that I cannot sort when trying to get the value into @NumOfProducts.